# MySQL will not update

Tags: php, mysql, sql

This is my first time on SO, so I'm not knowing about everything. I'm sorry. I have a problem with my site.  I want to update the viewed status of one of the rows.

This is my update code:

```
<?php
   if(isset($_POST['Submit'])){//if the submit button is clicked

      $sql= mysql_query ("UPDATE system_reports SET viewed=1 WHERE id =' ".$row['id']." ' ");
      $conn->query($sql) or die("Cannot update");//update or error
   }
?>
```

But when I click on the button, I get: `Cannot Update`. The connection of DB is fine. So I don't know what is the problem. ID is a realy working variable.

So is my rows working:

```
<?php
   function spam_Draw() {
      $a = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM system_reports WHERE viewed=0");
      while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($a)) {    
         echo $row['id']." <a href='http://warrock-hack.net/profiel/".$row['user'] . "/'>Gedupeerde</a> <a href='" . $row['report_url'] . "'> Ga naar het probleem toe!</a>    " . $row['reason'];
         echo '<br>';
         echo '<INPUT TYPE="Submit" VALUE="Update the Record" NAME="Submit"> ';
      }
   }
?>
```

I hope someone can help me out! Thanks..

Regards,

John.

Comment: You shouldn't need the single quotes around the ID, as they are usually an int field.

Comment: are you sure `row['id']` exists after the form is submitted?

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` see if it yields anything.

Comment: Some notes: Use mysqli or PDO because mysql_* is very old. also watch out for SQL Injections. you need to escape your params

Comment: First problem: `row['id']` doesn't automatically get sent when the form is submitted. You need to send it as a POST value. Possibly with a hidden input. Second problem: You are mixing `mysql` with `mysqli`/`pdo`. See answer by @MarcB

Comment: I try'd error reporting. And i get this: Notice: Use of undefined constant QUERY_STRING - assumed 'QUERY_STRING' in /home/janveuf58/domains/warrock-hack.net/public_html/sources/beheer/spam.php on line 73

Answer (score 2):

Your DB calls are totally wrong. `mysql_query()` returns a query handle representing the results of your query (or boolean false on failure). You're taking that handle, and feeding it to some OTHER database library.

`mysql`, `mysqli` and `PDO` database handles/results are NOT interchangeable, and the libraries cannot be mixed together like that.

You probably want something more like:

```
$sql = "UPDATE....  " . $row['id'];  // no mysql_query() call, just defining a string
$result = $conn->query($sql);
```

Plus, die()ing with a fixed string for your error message is utterly useless. The DB libraries can TELL you what the problem was:

```
$result = $conn->query($sql) or die(mysqli_error()); // assuming mysqli
```

Comment: This solves part of the problem. But the next issue is `$row['id']` does not exist after the form is submitted...